# Create Instance of anonymous Controller and use its methods

Tags: java, reflection, javafx

Good morning dear board

There is a way in Java to make instances of anonymous classes:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("method name", parameterTypes)
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

If I wished making new Instances of JavaFX Controllers I would just do this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
           "MyClass.fxml"));
MyClassCtrl ctrl = loader.getController();
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
ctrl.methodNameOfMyClassCtrl();
```

But now I have an example where I need to do instances of Controllers and use their methods, which aren't known while coding. They get known by runtime, depends on which Button was clicked by the user.

So what I need is a combination of the both techniques descriped above. Now I made following, but it won't work.

```
String methodName = "myMethod";
String className = "MyController";

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource( className + ".fxml" ));
Class c = Class.forName(className);
loader.setController(c);
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, null);
m.invoke(null, null);
```

I doubt, I'm the first trying something like this - so you guys are my last chance.

Thanks and best regards
Enis

Comment: I don't understand why you do this.  You can place an `fx:controller` attribute in the controller and the FXML loader will automatically create the controller for the FXML and invoke the `initialize` method on the controller.  So you dynamically load your FXML and the JavaFX system takes care of everything else for you - you don't need set the controller to the loader in Java code nor use reflection to invoke a method.

Comment: What does "won't work" mean?  Is there some error trace or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to mix reflection API with your controllers, see this

```
String methodName = "myMethod";
String className = "MyController";

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource( className + ".fxml" ));
Class c = Class.forName("mypackage." + className);
Object obj = c.newInstance();
loader.setController(obj);
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
m.invoke(obj);
```

However bear in mind that reflection maybe slow down your app speed and refactoring maybe hard to do. If you explain your use case there can be other approach using OOP like inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll check your solution till tomorrow.
Yes I got inheritance also in mind. In my opinion reflection should not be slower as other OOP. I'll do a performance check at the end for both solutions! Thanks Uluk!